# Change site language in wordpress with Rewrite API

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, internationalization

I have a site on wordpress and want to make language switcher english/russian. I want to implement the next url scheme:

1. Default (english) urls look like that: site.com/company
2. Russian urls look like that: site.com/ru/company

I want to make next programming handling:
When url like `site.com/ru/company` comes to WP, I detect this situation and internally call page `site.com/company` with query string `lang=ru` for the appropriate handling this `lang` in page template file `company.php`.

But I don't want to make external redirect (301) through the browser, and handle that situation internally.

How to implement this scheme with Rewrite API ?

Comment: Did you ever achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I did. As far as I remember I used apache's modrewrite for that

Comment: Excellent news!! Would you detail a little bit? :)

Comment: It was a long time ago. Unfortunately I don't remember details (